# How to dimensionalize a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing this, other than a for-loop and unpacking manually...

Imagine I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
| id | value |    date    | name |
| -- | ----- | ---------- | ---- |
| 1  |   5   | 2021-04-05 | foo  |
| 1  |   6   | 2021-04-06 | foo  |
| 5  |   7   | 2021-04-05 | bar  |
| 5  |   9   | 2021-04-06 | bar  |
```

If I wanted to dimensionalize this, I could split it up into two different tables. One, perhaps, would contain "meta" information about the person, and the other serving as "records" that would all relate back to one person... a pretty simple idea as far as SQL-ian ideas go...

The resulting tables would look like this...

Meta

```
| id | name |
| -- | ---- |
| 1  | foo  |
| 5  | bar  |
```

Records

```
| id | value |    date    |
| -- | ----- | ---------- |
| 1  |   5   | 2021-04-05 |
| 1  |   6   | 2021-04-06 |
| 5  |   7   | 2021-04-05 |
| 5  |   9   | 2021-04-06 |
```

My question is, how can I achieve this "dimensionalizing" of a dataframe with pandas, without having to write a for loop on the unique `id` key field and unpacking manually?

Comment: They would just be the same column names from the original dataframe... not sure if I understand your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about this not as "splitting" the existing dataframe, but as creating two new dataframes from the original. You can do this in a couple of lines:

```
meta = df[['id','name']].drop_duplicates() #Select the relevant columns and remove duplicates
records = df.drop("name", axis=1) #Replicate the original dataframe but drop the name column
```

Comment: Beautifully elegant solution, thank you this works perfectly! <3

Answer (score 1):

You could `drop_duplicates` based off a subset of columns for the columns you want to keep. For the second dataframe, you can `drop` the name column:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['id', 'name']).loc[:,['id', 'name']] # perigon's answer is simpler with df[['id','name']].drop_duplicates()
df2 = df.drop('name', axis=1)
df1, df2
```

Output:

```
(   id name
 0   1  foo
 2   5  bar,
    id  value        date
 0   1      5  2021-04-05
 1   1      6  2021-04-06
 2   5      7  2021-04-05
 3   5      9  2021-04-06)
```